# Create in Backbone.JS doesn't update ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, backbone.js

Currently I'm working on a Backbone.js todo-list application. I'm building the frontend with Backbone and I'm building my backend with PHP and MySQL.

I've managed to build a save and delete function, but currently I got one problem: when I save a model, the model doesn't have an ID and gets assigned a temporary ID by Backbone. Then when I save the model gets an ID assigned by the server and the server returns the new model.

This is my model and collection code:

```
app.TodoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "ID",
    defaults: {
        "title": "Do me!",
        "date": "24-06-1992",
        "completed": false
    }
});

app.TodoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.TodoModel,
    url: '/src/todos.php'
});
```

And this is the code which I use to create the model:

```
app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#todoApp',
    initialize: function(){
        this.input = this.$('#addTodo');
        this.todoCollection = new app.TodoCollection(); // Create collection

        this.todoCollection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
        this.todoCollection.on('add', this.addOne, this);

        this.todoCollection.fetch();
    },
    events: {
        'keypress #addTodo': 'createTodo'
    },
    addOne: function(todo){
        var view = new app.TodoView({model: todo});
        $('#todoList').append(view.render().el);
    },
    addAll: function(){
        console.log('reset');
        this.$('#todoList').html(''); // clean the todo list
        this.todoCollection.each(this.addOne, this);
    },
    createTodo: function(e){
        if (e.which !== 13 || !this.input.val().trim()) { // ENTER_KEY = 13
            return;
        }
        this.todoCollection.create(this.newAttributes(), {
                wait:true,
                success: function(model, response) {
                    console.log("Added todo");
                    console.log(response);
                },  
                error: function(model, response) {
                    console.log("Adding failed");
                    console.log(response);
                }
        }),
        this.input.val(''); // clean input box
    },
    newAttributes: function(){
        return {
            title: this.input.val().trim(),
            date: new Date(),
            completed: false
        }
    }
});
```

So far so good right? But now the problems start. Even when I use `wait: true` in the create, the old model data gets used. So the ID doesn't get updated with the new ID, which means I can't call the delete function because that requires a valid ID.

Also the date shows differently, this is the date when you first add a todo: `MON OCT 26 2015 08:59:22 GMT+0100 (CET)` and this is the date when you refresh the page: `2015-10-26`. This probably also have to do with using the old model data.

My application is hosted here: http://todoapp.lusenet.com/

TL;DR: Model gets created and saved at the server, but the frontend doesn't use the returned model and uses the old model instead. How can I use the returned models data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the problem was in what I returned from the server. This is the code I used:

```
$addTodoQuery = "INSERT INTO todos (title,date,completed) VALUES ('$title','$date','$completed')";
if(mysqli_query($con,$addTodoQuery)){
    $ID = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $getTodoQuery = "SELECT * FROM todos WHERE ID='$ID'";
    $todos = mysqli_query($con,$getTodoQuery) or die("error"); // http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
    while ($todo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($todos)) {
        $rows[] = $todo;
    }
    print_r(json_encode($rows));
} else {
    echo "Fail";
}
```

So that printed an array containing one object, while Backbone was expecting just an object. So I changed `print_r(json_encode($rows))` to `echo json_encode($rows[0]);` and now everything works fine!